# This shows up in algebraic topology, right?

Tags: algebraic-topology, multilinear-algebra

(For the purposes of this question, please identify each natural number with the set of all smaller numbers. For example, $3 = \{0,1,2\}$.)

I've been thinking about writing up an elementary account of $k$-vectors and wedge products that I can give to students in their last year of high school or their first year of university. For example, I'd like to teach determinants and cross-products in this way. I had in mind something like this: we define $\Lambda^r\mathbb{R}^n$ (we could even denote this $\Lambda^{r,n}$) as the set of functions $$f:(r \rightarrow n) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ satisfying the following condition.

> **Axiom.** For all permutations $\pi : r \rightarrow r$ and all functions $\varphi : r \rightarrow n$, we have $f(\varphi \circ \pi) = f(\varphi)\mathrm{sgn}(\pi).$

For example, if $f$ satisfies the above axiom, then for each $\varphi : r \rightarrow n$ that fails to be injective, we have $f(\varphi)=0$. To see this, let $\pi$ denote a permutation that transposes two elements on which $\varphi$ returns the same value, we have:

$$f(\varphi) = f(\varphi \circ \pi) = f(\varphi)\mathrm{sgn}(\pi) = -f(\varphi).$$

Hence $f(\varphi)=0$.

Anyway, as I was toying with this, I suddenly had a vague recollection of seeing this kind of thing in an algebraic topology subject I took a couple of years ago; it had something to do with abstract simplicial complexes.

> **Question.** Am I recalling correctly that there's a notion/definition/construction similar to this (and probably more general), that's used in algebraic topology in connection with abstract simplicial complexes?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly it is that you are asking, please?

Comment: @Tyrone, what's unclear about: "Question. Am I recalling correctly that something like this is used in algebraic topology in connection with abstract simplicial complexes? If so, can someone explain the connection?"

Comment: What "something like this" is.

Comment: @Tyrone, a similar or more general definition/notion/construction.

Comment: @Tyrone, is the new wording of the Question part any clearer?

Comment: I would not say it is used in algebraic topology in connection with abstract simplicial complexes. Instead it is used in algebraic topology in connection with smooth manifolds, namely in the definition of the de Rham cohomology. See for example the book of Bott and Tu.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd introduce the notion this way rather than one of the standard ways. It's not like this is going to be any easier for a high school senior or college freshman than the standard treatments (via exterior products, or Laplace expansion, or whatever). It is effectively only a notational variant, so why introduce your own notation?

Comment: Then there is a somewhat indirect connection with abstract simplicial complexes, namely that every smooth manifold is homeomorphic to a simplicial complex, and the simplicial cohomology with $\mathbb{R}$-coefficients is isomorphic to the de Rham cohomology.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, the standard approach uses quotients of graded algebras by graded ideals. How am I supposed to teach this? It's also a mistake to say that this is a notational variant. The notation ends up being exactly the same!